Azure event grid deadletter retries don't work
I am using Azure event grid for pub-sub. I configured a webhook for receiving the published event.
I have also configured deadletter but it doesn't seem to retry.
Everytime the webhook is down it just attempts 1 time and sends to deadletter blob after 5 minutes for all configuration.
The deliveryOutcome is NotFound and error is UndeliverableDueToClientError.
For example consider the below policy:

Ideally it should try attempt 2 times or send the event to deadletter after 30 minutes but it attempts only 1 time and the event is deadlettered after 5 minutes.


The deliveryOutcome is NotFound and error is UndeliverableDueToClientError.


If the deliveryOutcome is NotFound, Azure Event Grid may be having trouble finding the webhook endpoint. This can be due to incorrect URL or a DNS resolution issue.


As per the above condition the event should go to the dead letter message. but here I configured TTL and retry attempts is 30min and 2 attempts.

As per the document saying whenever the event decides the first policy (like TTL or retry Attempts) it will be dead lettered.


In your case the event got failed before 30min only that's the reason it went into the dead letter.

Shouldn't it attempt 1 more time before deadlettering as max attempts is set as 2? But it attempts only 1 time.

Can you please check all the configuration in your setup.

The screenshot I have shared is all that should be required for retrying . Is there something else do I need to check?

Your webhook is returning a client error (e.g., 404, 400, etc.). When Azure Event Grid receives a client error, it often does not retry the delivery, treating it as a permanent failure.
